# PUT request that updates an array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose, put

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, my brain is a bit fried from looking at so many different articles and trying different things.

Using mongoose, I am currently trying to make a PUT route that can take an array of objects and replace the entire collection with the new set of data.

Where I am calling the `findOneAndUpdate()` function in the put route, I tried using the `save()` function. But when I do that, rather than replacing the existing data with what I am trying to replace it with, it just adds the objects to the collection as new items and keeps the existing data. `findOneAndUpdate()` doesn't do anything and then the `console.log(stats);` fires.

Here is my PUT request in the route file:

```
router.put("/", async (req, res) => {        
  const { PassingTouchdowns, PassingYards, PlayerID, Receptions, ReceivingTouchdowns, ReceivingYards, RushingTouchdowns, RushingYards, Week } = req.body;
  const statsField = {};
  if(PassingTouchdowns) statsField.PassingTouchdowns = PassingTouchdowns;
  if(PassingYards) statsField.PassingYards = PassingYards;
  if(PlayerID) statsField.PlayerID = PlayerID;
  if(Receptions) statsField.Receptions = Receptions;
  if(ReceivingYards) statsField.ReceivingYards = ReceivingYards;
  if(RushingTouchdowns) statsField.RushingTouchdowns = RushingTouchdowns;
  if(RushingYards) statsField.RushingYards = RushingYards;
  if(Week) statsField.Week = Week;

try {
    let playerid = await PlayerGameStatsByWeek.find({ PlayerID });
    newStats = new PlayerGameStatsByWeek({
      statsField
    });

    //For Adding multiple objects
    req.body.forEach(function(obj) {
      var stats = new PlayerGameStatsByWeek(obj);
      PlayerGameStatsByWeek.findOneAndUpdate(
        playerid, 
        { $set: stats },
        { new: true }
      );
      console.log(stats);
    });
    
    res.send({ msg: "Stats Updated!" });

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.send({ msg: "Server Error" })
}
});
```

Here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PlayerGameStatsByWeekSchema = Schema(
  [{
    PassingTouchdowns: String,
    PassingYards: String,
    PlayerID: String,
    Receptions: String,
    ReceivingTouchdowns: String,
    ReceivingYards: String,
    RushingTouchdowns: String,
    RushingYards: String,
    Week: String
  }]
);

const Stats = module.exports = mongoose.model('stats', PlayerGameStatsByWeekSchema);

module.exports.getPlayerGameStatsByWeek = function(callback, limit) {
    Stats.find(callback).limit(limit)};
```

Here is a small example of what I would want to throw at the PUT request:

```
[
    {
        "PassingTouchdowns": "0",
        "PassingYards": "0",
        "PlayerID": "123456",
        "Receptions": "6.8",
        "ReceivingTouchdowns": "0",
        "ReceivingYards": "0",
        "RushingTouchdowns": "8.5",
        "RushingYards": "900.8",
        "Week": "1"
    },
    {
        "PassingTouchdowns": "1",
        "PassingYards": "14",
        "PlayerID": "987654",
        "Receptions": "2.5",
        "ReceivingTouchdowns": "4",
        "ReceivingYards": "30",
        "RushingTouchdowns": "0",
        "RushingYards": "0",
        "Week": "2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace whole collection with data you better use mongodb aggregations, $out stage https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/